# Lightweight matrix of boolean values

Tags: c, optimization, memory, boolean

I need to implement a very large matrix, say NxN in Standard C. The matrix must store a truth table, that is

```
matrix[i][j] = [true|false]
```

I know I could simply use a `int` matrix, or `boolean` type if using C99, but was looking for the most lightweight solution in terms of memory.

Comment: What's wrong with using one bit per cell and storing bits in, say, `unsigned long`s?

Comment: @n.m., that is actually the solution I've implemented so far, but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient solution (and very interesting answers are coming along :) )

Comment: Is the truth table equally filled with 1 and 0? Is it random? Is it sparse or dense? How much are typical N and M?

Comment: If you know a bit more about statistical properties of the data, you perhaps can select a good compression scheme for it. Otherwise it's the most efficient method.

Comment: I must implement a percolation cluster, and every element of the matrix must be filled with 0 or 1 with a varying probaility. I'm particulary interested in the case the matrix is dense. N and M should be ~10000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most lightweight solution in terms of memory is saving eight boolean in a char:

```
unsigned char getBit(char byte, unsigned short bit){
    assert(bit < 8);
    return byte&(1<<bit);
}
```

Then you can store a `N x 8M` matrix by saving the bytes in each row. If many of those bytes are empty then you should use a sparse matrix format, for example compressed spares row.

Comment: could this help avoiding cache trashing too?

Comment: Well, if you're going to iterate over rows - maybe. The solution above uses exactly one bit for a boolean. However, when calculating or manipulating your matrix you should avoid using a function like getBit and manipulate the bytes directly using `|,^,&,~` and constant bitset marks as `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x04` to ensure optimization.

Comment: Thanks, actually I found some useful macros to deal with bitwise operations directly on the code without using any function... hope it will work... :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a hash implementation or a list of lists if the matrix is particularly sparse.

Also if the i or j is less than the largest integer your system can store you can pack a boolean bitset into a single integer with each bit corresponding to one index. You can then access or modify this using bitwise operations.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it what std::bitset is for ?

Comment: I'm not using C++ right now, anyway thanks for the reference :)

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a more efficient solution

If you want to store more than 1 boolean in single  bit, you need to use some compression.

Compression will work only on non-random data; And random access to compressed data can be slow.

Easiest one method is RLE (compress each row independently). A bit more complex is storing data in sparse matrix (only if you have much more 0 values than 1; this method can compress multi-dimensional data).

Much more complex compression is used here: http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~kewu/fastbit/index.html It is named ["Word-Aligned Hybrid compression scheme"](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~kewu/ps/LBNL-49626.html)